# Adding listener to child nodes in Expandable List Item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have used a code given in tutorial 
http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/12/expandable-list-and-checkboxes.html
I have attached an image of the ExpandableListView 
[image]

```
SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
        new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            createGroupList(),  
            R.layout.child_row, 
            new String[] { "CityName" },
            new int[] { R.id.childname },       
            createChildList(),  
            R.layout.child_row, 
            new String[] { "citydetails", "city" }, 
            new int[] { R.id.childname, R.id.city}  
        );

    setListAdapter( expListAdapter );
```

I need some code example on how to add listeners to individual child nodes for example clicking on Address should take the user to another activity.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have your activity override the the onChildClick method:

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    //implement logic to start the appropriate activity for this child.
}
```

From the android dev site: [onChildClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html).

I also recommend downloading the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html).  You can learn more on setting it up [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html).

Comment: AFAIK, this method only works if you're trying to catch a click on a list view item i.e. an entire row. If your row is composed of multiple views, this method does not identify the child (of the ViewGroup in the row) that was clicked. It is called with the reference to the containing ViewGroup. To illustrate, say your row is composed of a `LinearLayout` `root` with two `TextView`'s `child1` and `child2`. If we click on `child1`, the `onChildClick` will be called, but with a reference to `root` not `child1` as we might have thought.

Comment: Thanks for the info Manish.  I've yet to create a expandable listview with child items that have multiple clickable views.

Comment: @Scott thanks, but how could I get hold of the phone number displayed in the childnode of that group or parentnode, so that I can call an activity to make a call to that particular number.

Comment: You would use the parameters of the onChildClick method.  Either use "view" to get the data from the clicked list item.  Or you could use the groupPosition and childPosition.  You can set your group and child data you send into your adapter as field variables in your activity.  Then use the groupPosition and childPosition to retrieve the data for the clicked child of the group.

Comment: See @Scott answer above (+1). I now understand what you're trying to do. If all you need is the phone number a given row represents, just use `onChildClick` and utilize the `groupPosition` and `childPosition` to fetch your data from the adapter using `SimpleExpandableListAdapter::getChild`. You shouldn't need a custom adapter for this case. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @ManishGupta   '((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.childname)).getText().toString();' this is not working I get only the heading Phone for that field but I need associated phone number with that field, how do you use groupPosition and ChildPosition... am I missing something...let me know thanks.

Comment: public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    //implement logic to start the appropriate activity for this child.
}. You have all three required params in this function. Getting your data should be straightforward.

Comment: @ManishGupta  
  `public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
       
        
        String number1 = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.childname)).getText().toString();
        System.out.println("Number1"+number1);
        if(childPosition == 1){
         String number = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.childname)).getText().toString();
         
         System.out.println("Number "+number);
        }
        
        return super.onChildClick(parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
    }`

Comment: @Manish Gupta  any changes in the code I have to put...expecting your reply...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot add listener's to your child views using the example above. You will have to have a custom adapter. In this custom adapter's `getChildView` and `getGroupView` you can provide your own listeners. Eg.

```
public View getGroupView(
            int groupPosition, 
            boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, 
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewGroup viewGroup = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplication().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (li != null) {
                viewGroup = (ViewGroup) li.inflate(R.layout.listitems_group, parent, false);
            }
        } else {
            viewGroup = (ViewGroup) convertView;
        }

            Button button = (Button) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.group_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 void onClick(View v) {
                     // Do what you want here
                 }
            });
            return viewGroup;
}
```

Here I have buttons in my GroupView which I want to add onClick listener's for.

Comment: I could not understand the code fully, you mean to say I should not use  SimpleExpandableListAdapter  and should use Custom adapter, I am new to android any links for the better understanding.thanks.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that. See this somewhat related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568086/what-adapter-to-use-for-expandablelistview-with-non-textview-views

Comment: what Scott gave below works but the question is how to get text from that child node...